# App icon is not able to set for iPad pro using phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, icons

I am creating application using Phonegap. I am able to set the icon for other devices except iPad pro. I have tried following code in 'Config.xml' file to set the icon:

```
<icon height="167" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
```

But still it is not showing in Xcode-> Images.xcassets-> iPad Pro app. and also not able to see on iPad pro.
Anyone able to set the icon for iPad pro using Config.xml?

Answer (score 1):

```
<icon platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
```

Works on Ionic with command `ionic resources`.